# winform/radtreeview/c#: using RadTreeview in winform with DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I need to use **RadTreeView** of telerik to show a tree of clients. Working with Nodes.Add is too slow and I would like to know an alternative to work using the **DataSource** of the tree and seting my query there.

my dto is:

```
public class DTOClient 
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public int ParentId {get; set;}
}
```

Is it possible using **Datasource**?

Answer (score 0):

Following the provided information, I can suggest you two options:

1. Load data on demand: this feature helps reduce performance and memory costs incurred when all nodes are loaded at once. The following help article demonstrates a sample approach how to use it: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/treeview/data-binding/load-on-demand
2. Data binding to self referencing data: appropriate when you have a single collection of objects where each object has an ID and ParentID: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/treeview/data-binding/binding-to-self-referencing-data

I hope this information helps.

Comment: I have a RadTreeView bound to Object-relational data with `DisplayMember` and `ChildMember` specified. It works and I can view the tree, however when trying to access the tree in code, it is empty(0 nodes) and throws an index out of range error